# Using IHTTPActionResult to return JSONP for CORS request compatibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsonp, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to make IHTTPActionResult JSONP instead of JSON or XML?

Here is the controller action I'm trying to make return JSONP:

```
public IHttpActionResult getCountry()
{
    LocationDB db = new LocationDB();
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<Country> countries = db.getCountries();
        return Ok(countries);
    }
    catch
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890967/intercept-jsonresult-and-wrap-it-as-string/19893004#19893004